# Magento2.3 checkout page getting error

Tags: checkout, error, api, magento2.3

I used magento2.3 - when i go to checkout page this error comes below.please if anyone know regarding this reply me

```
Error occurred during "shipping_address" processing. Error occurred during "customAttributes" processing. A custom attribute is specified with a missing attribute code. Verify the code and try again.
```

Comment: Did you have any customization in checkout steps? Special for Shipping Address or Billing Address.  Is there any custom field for Billing or Shipping Address?

Comment: Yes I have to add customer attribute "Suite".

Comment: Hi @RvSingh, did you solve it?

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by this commit https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/c15e194a9c5395d6cc703813feea8ed6efc4f6d5#diff-5caf9b4a7016097c6254817ce41d982e

The problem was that it was using 0, 1, etc. as keys and 0 evaluates to false in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by creating the extension attributes.If you have already created then you have missed a change in the js file

Vendor_Name/Module_Name/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes , function( key, value ) {

                    if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                        value = value['value'];

                   // assign value to key ..add this if you have missed
                        key = this.attribute_code;
                    }

                    shippingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                    shippingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;

                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding !!